# FlutterAppDelegate make iOS app openURL not called

Tags: flutter

I am importing Flutter SDK to my native iOS project . doing as this guide

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=no-engine-vc-uikit-objc-tab

In this guide , it recommends that we should inherited from  FlutterAppDelegate
[image]

But after doing this . I found that the methods in my origin app delegate like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
```

those methods will not get called , which makes my app not working well when invoked from safari or anyother app.

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer here:

TLDR:
`handleOpenURL` and `openURL:sourceApplication:` are deprecated, use `openURL:options:` will make things right

1st

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

those two deprecated API will not called when AppDelegate is inherited from FlutterAppDelegate.
use this api for instead

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

2nd when you code contains  `application:openURL:options:`
the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
```

can be called normally and works well